# if tag affecting Struts 2 include tag

Tags: jsp, struts2

I'm trying to include a jsp page to another jsp page. For example i have a `main.jsp` page that includes `extra.jsp` but it doesn't work. `extra.jsp` contains a Struts if tag and when i remove it the include works fine. what can be the possible problems?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please share your code..

Comment: Are you missing the taglib declaration in the included file? In any case, hour do you expect help with the information provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem was in your `if condition` means if you mentioned any condition then it won't work correctly for eg: in extra.jsp

```
<s:if test='(#session.name == "admin")'>
</s:if>
```

("name" could be any name of your application.)

Now if you try to open `extra.jsp` it will ask the name containing with admin.

If you enter any wrong name page won't open until with the correct name so, directly it comes to the else block (or) the web page will be shown like blank page.

In your case, problem might be the same means, if condition is present with some condition probably it is showing error.

Comment: Are you saying that because the `if` test evaluated to false it's still being included, but not displaying anything?

Comment: no, actually i said if `if tag` contain any condition until it satisfies that condition that page won't open(any page with if tag) if `if tag` present on the upper side (say before the code). Eg:`<body><s:if test='(#session.name == "admin")'><jsp:include page="image.jsp"></jsp:include>   
</s:if></body>` Here if you give admin then it shows the image page otherwise it won't it will go to the else block(if it is present) other wise it will shows blank.

Comment: That's what I said: the file *is* being included, but nothing is showing because the `<s:if>` tag is evaluating to false.

Comment: it wasn't in the condition itself it was what was inside the condition that was the problem that's why the whole page wasn't included. thanks for all the replies